# Websocket not receiving messages from Django Channels server

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm currently working on a project utilizing Django Channels for WebSocket communication. While the WebSocket connection is successfully established, I'm encountering an issue where messages aren't received on the client side.

**Summary:**

- WebSocket connection is established without errors.
- Django Channels server is sending messages, as verified.
- However, the client-side WebSocket does not seem to receive any messages.

**Code Snippets:**

*asgi.py:*

```py
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
import transposys_main.routing
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'transposys_main.settings')
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        URLRouter(transposys_main.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
    ),
})
```

*consumer.py:*

```py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class DepartmentCreatedConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        logger.info(f"WebSocket connected: {self.channel_name}")
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        logger.info(f"WebSocket disconnected: {self.channel_name}")

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        logger.info(f"WebSocket message received: {text_data}")

        try:
            text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
            message_type = text_data_json.get('type')
            message = text_data_json.get('message')

            if message_type == 'department.created':
                logger.info(f"New Department: {message}")

        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            logger.error(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")

    async def department_created(self, event):
        try:
            logger.info(f"Department created event received: {event['message']}")
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'type': 'department.created',
                'message': event['message'],
            }))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error sending WebSocket message: {e}")
```

*routing.py:*

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from .consumers import DepartmentCreatedConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/department_creation/$', DepartmentCreatedConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

**Server Configuration:**

- WSGI: `waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 transposys_main.wsgi:application`
- ASGI: `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 transposys_main.asgi:application`

**Additional Information:**

- Despite successful connection, no messages are received in the HTML page or console.